# Player's jumping compromised after reloading the scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, application-restart

First of all, please don't get too technical: I've only been studying Unity coding for two months and I'm not a programmer in general! I'm a total beginner! :-)
So, I'm building a game where you control a ball on a treadmill avoiding endless spawning obstacles by shifting left-right and jumping.
I set up a restart function after game over with SceneManager.LoadScene method, it works, but after reloading the jumping function gets compromised: it looks like there's an invisible wall above the player blocking its jumps. And it also looks like it's an "additive" issue: if I die and restart again, the player jumps even less, until it just doesn't jump at all. The other functions seem fine.
Any idea why that happens?

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    //Jump code:

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnLane)
                {
                    Jump();
                }
    }
void Jump()
        {
            playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * forceMult, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isOnLane = false;
        }
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
        {
            //checks if player is touching the ground
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Lane"))
            {
                isOnLane = true;
            }
        }
```

Restart code:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

    //restart game by clicking Restart Button
        public void RestartGame()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Silly question but still: did you check the scene hierarchy? Maybe there some actual invisible object (with Collider but with no MeshFilter or MeshRenderer component). Maybe there are objects in your scene that are not destroyed after scene reloads.
Try using OnCollisionEnter to DebugLog if your player actually hits something

Comment: We would need to see your scene loading and jumping code. Maybe a screenshot of your hierarchy.

Comment: @obywan fair question, but no, there's nothing above my player. The closest thing would be the camera and an empty object used for Transform, but they are both behind the player.

Comment: @Selzier I would really like to post the codes, but I can't seem to be able to format it in the comment so that it's readable... and I can't seem to find help on the internet about how to do it! Uhm... can you help me? Sorry for the silly trouble!

Comment: Edit your question to include the code. Use the Code block (looks like this { } right next to the image button in stack text editor)

Comment: @Selzier code added! To clarify, now that I notice, "playerRb" is the rigidbody of the player, set with the GetComponent method, and forceMult is a float initialized in the Start method of the script.

Comment: Is the player in the scene that is being reloaded? Or is he in the same scene as GameManager?

Comment: @Selzier It's all in one scene. The GameManager script is applied to an empty object.

Comment: Can you add `Debug.Log(forceMult);` right above `playerRb.AddForce...` ? And check the console to see if the force of the jump is the same after you reload your scene.

Comment: Solved! I found out that the problem was caused by the fact that I was modyfing gravity by multiplying it by 3 in the Start() of my GameManager, but after restart the gravity wasn't reset to its original value and so it was multiplied by 3 AGAIN, making it 9 times bigger, and so on.
I tried storing the initial gravity in a variable initialGravity, then applying the modification on Start Button pressing and resetting to the initialGravity on game over... and it worked!
Sorry for not mentioning the mod, but I realised it's hard to select which info to share!
Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: I will note that my answer is correct as it says to "reset the player and his physics".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that additive scene loading is being used when there is only a single scene. It would be good to break these up into 2 scenes:

- A scene for GameManager & the Player object
- A scene for the level itself which is being reloaded

This way the GameManager is not being reloaded and the player is not being reloaded. Upon reload you need to "reset" variables for the player back to 0 and move him to a starting position.

RestartGame needs some logic to reset the player and his physics.

```
public void RestartGame()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
            playerController.playerRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            playerController.playerRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            playerTransform.position = spawnLocation.tranform.position;
        }
```

You probably want to unload the scene, wait for 1 frame, and then load the scene. This way variables in the scene get reset properly.

```
public void RestartGame()
{
    SceneManager.UnloadScene(scene);
    playerController.playerRb.isKinematic = true; // Try setting kinematic between scenes
    StartCoroutine(RestartLoad());
}

private IEnumerator RestartLoad() 
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    // Reset the player here
    SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
    playerController.playerRb.isKinematic = false; // Player can use physics again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue before. It was due to the gravity modifier, just like code before.

```
Physics.gravity *= gravityModifier;
```

Physics was not reset before loading the scene and so its new value from a first game was kept and multiplied at each reload.

Solved it by reseting the gravity before loading the scene

```
 public void RestartGame()
        {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -9.8f, 0); //The default gravity in project settings
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
```